# Gaussian integral over complex values

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate $|\int_{\gamma}e^{z^2}dz|$ for $\gamma$ is a segment from $(-3-3i)$ to $3i$, and fail badly.

Tried to express $e^{z^2}$ as Taylor serie, but apparently it got me nowhere.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that absolute value containing all the line integral?

Comment: yes, sorry - editting mistake